# jquery ajax long pending status type put and json only on android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ajax, json

The same code is working fine on every desktop browser (Safari, Chrome, Firefox, IE) or iPad 4 in 1-2 seconds. But fails with long pending (2-4 minutes) when testing on Android tablet (4.2.2) browser / Google Chrome 31 or iPad 2 UMTS.

jquery version = 1.10.2

```
var datasend;
$.putJSON = function(url, data, callback) {
    return $.ajax({
        url : url + "?_=" + jQuery.now(),
        beforeSend: function(par1, par2, par3){
            console.log('beforeSend: ',par1, par2, par3);
        },
        error: function (par1, par2, par3){
            console.log('error: ',par1, par2, par3);
        },
        success : callback || function() {

        },
        data : JSON.stringify(data),
        timeout: 15000,
        dataType : 'json',
        type : 'PUT',
        cache: false,
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    });
};

$('#postklick').on('click', function() {
    $.putJSON('/rest/idea', datasend, function(data, statusText, xhr) {
        var response = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(response.exception);
    }).fail(function(xhr, status, statusError) {
        console.log(statusError);
    });
    return false;
});

datasend = {
    "name": "idee",
    "description": "adasdasdasa",
    "base64Image": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAeoAAAGkCAYAAAD+P2YmAA..."
};
```

**Response Header:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, origin, content-type
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
access-control-allow-credentials: true
X-REST-Response-State: ok
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 24 Jan 2014 14:55:18 GMT
Content-Length: 811
```

**Request Header:**

```
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Length: 326765
Connection: keep-alive
```

In **chrome//net-internals/#events** I see:
...

```
[st = 10] HTTP_STREAM_PARSER_READ_HEADERS --> net_error = -101 (ERR_CONNECTION_RESET)
[st = 128859] HTTP_TRANSACTION_RESTART_AFTER_ERROR --> net_error = -101 (ERR_CONNECTION_RESET)
```

...

Any ideas?